# Bitbucket's pipelines with Java Maven project and JFX

Tags: java, maven, javafx, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

my team and I have a maven project using jdk1.8 (not open jdk) and javaFX for our UI. It's working well and there still a lot of work to do and we'd like to use the pipelines from Bitbucket to make continuous integration on the go.

I tried to use a simple .yml file :

```
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - maven
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn -B verify # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose
```

But there is my problem, We are developping with IntelliJ and jdk1.8 where javaFX is standard and automatically included in the project. But the pipelines tries to use openjdk1.8, and can't find the javaFX classes (especially the jfxrt.jar file).

If I do nothing and try as it is, the Maven error is :

```
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/main/java/JFX/MainJFX.java:[3,26] package javafx.application does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/main/java/JFX/MainJFX.java:[4,19] package javafx.fxml does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/main/java/JFX/MainJFX.java:[5,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/main/java/JFX/MainJFX.java:[6,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/main/java/JFX/MainJFX.java:[7,20] package javafx.stage does not exist
```

I tried to include the jfxrt.jar file to maven to my pom.xml as a system dependency like that :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
            <version>${java.version}</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But then Maven warns me he does not find the jfxrt.jar file :

```
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for javafx:jfxrt:jar refers to a non-existing file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar @ line 34, column 25
```

Mainly because he is using openjdk and not jdk.

I also tried to put the jfxrt.jar file inside the repository and make a dependency to it, it works but Maven warns me it's not proper to do it like that :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/dependency/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

and the warning :

```
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.oracle:javafx:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/dependency/jfxrt.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 34, column 25[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

My question is how to either force Maven to use JDK and not OpenJDK, or how to make a nice dependency to javaFX so Maven can verify our project everytime we push and not warn us.

Thank you all for your future responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Oracle's licensing of Java, Docker Hub no longer hosts official images containing the Oracle JDK. All the official images, including [the Maven one you're using](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/8ab542b907e69c5269942bcc0915d8dffcc7e9fa/jdk-7/Dockerfile), are now based on OpenJDK instead.

To use Oracle Java, you'll need to [build your own Docker image as the Pipelines build environment](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-docker-images-as-build-environments-792298897.html) (relatively simple), or find a trusted source for a Docker image with the JDK in it. (It's pretty easy to find these via Google search, because this is a common problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Frist: JavaFX ist part of the OpenJDK. This setup works for me since the open beta of piplines:

the yaml file

```
image: maven:3.3.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn clean install
```

and here the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artifact.id</artifactId>
    <name>my.app.name</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- goal is 'mvn jfx:jar' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>package.to.my.main.class</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```